# Jquery Post with dynamic key

Tags: jquery, post, dynamic, key

I would like to send a post request. But I have to change the key.

```
function call(obj) {
    console.log("Call " + obj.value);
    if (obj.value == 1) 
    {
        $.post( "index.htm", { '"webdata".web[1].Taster': '1'} );
    }
```

I would like to change [1] to a dynamic different number.
To take a car between with + + do not work.

Do you have any idea?
Thank you

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain the exected parameter form ? like "webdata".web[1].Taster  as a string  , or do you expect to get this value then treat it as a key name ?

Comment: If the expected key name is an object value , could you show us a sample of your webdata object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way we set the keyname like  : "webdata".web[1].Taster

```js
objX={value:1}


function call(obj) {
    console.log("Call " + obj.value);
    if (obj.value == 1) 
    {
    var postParms = {};
    key='"webdata".web['+obj.value+'].Taster';
    console.log(key)
    
    postParms[key] = 1;   //or  ..= obj.value
        $.post( "index.htm",  postParms); 
    }
    
    }

call(objX)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way we set Ipsum as a keyname :

```js
objX={value:1}
webdata={
web:[
{Taster:"Lorem"},{Taster:"Ipsum"}
]
}

function call(obj) {
    console.log("Call " + obj.value);
    if (obj.value == 1) 
    {
    var postParms = {};
    key=webdata.web[obj.value].Taster;
    console.log(key)
    postParms[key] = 1;     
        $.post( "index.htm",  postParms); 
    }
    
    }
  
call(objX)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"webdata".web[1].Taster is a string I will send it to a Siemens plc. For the Javascript it is only a string that I have to change the number inside. Like "webdata".web[2].Taster or "webdata".web[35].Taster but in a dynamic way

Comment: Hi Daniel ! Welcome to stackoverflow ! It's preferable to edit your question than posting the explanation as an answer :)

Comment: Please edit the question instead of extending it via an answer.